# Automatically merging arbitrary Django models

Tags: python, django, database-design, django-models, django-orm

I have two Django-ORM managed databases that I'd like to merge. Both have a very similar schema, and both have the standard auth_users table, along with a few other shared tables that reference each other as well as auth_users, which I'd like to merge into a single database automatically.

Understandably, this could be very non-trivial depending upon the foreign-key relationships, and what constitutes a "unique" record in each table.

Does anyone know if there exists a tool to do this merge operation?

If nothing like this currently exists, I was considering writing my own management command, based on the standard loaddata command. Essentially, you'd use the standard dumpdata command to export tables from a source database, and then use a modified version of loaddata to "merge" them into the destination database.

For example, if I have databases A and B, and I want to merge database B into database A, then I'd want to follow a procedure according to the pseudo-code:

```
merge_database_dst = A
merge_database_src = B
for table in sorted(merge_database_dst.get_redundant_tables(merge_database_src), key=acyclic_dependency):
    key = table.get_unique_column_key()
    src_id_to_dst_id = {}
    for record_src in merge_database_src.table.objects.all():
        src_key_value = record_src.get_key_value(key)
        try:
            record_dst = merge_database_dst.table.objects.get(key)
            dst_key_value = record_dst.get_key_value(key)
        except merge_database_dst.table.DoesNotExist:
            record_dst = merge_database_dst.table(**[(k,convert_fk(v)) for k,v in record_src._meta.fields])
            record_dst.save()
            dst_key_value = record_dst.get_key_value(key)
        src_id_to_dst_id[(table,record_src.id)] = record_dst.id
```

The convert_fk() function would use the src_id_to_dst_id index to convert foreign key references in the source table to the equivalent IDs in the destination table.

To summarize, the algorithm would iterate over the table to be merged in the order of dependency, with parents iterated over first. So if we wanted to merge tables auth_users and mycustomprofile, which is dependent on auth_users, we'd iterate ['auth_users','mycustomprofile'].

Each merged table would need some sort of indicator documenting the combination of columns that denotes a universally unique record (i.e. the "key"). For auth_users, that might be the "username" and/or "email" column.

If the value of the key in database B already exists in A, then the record is not imported from B, but the ID of the existing record in A is recorded.

If the value of the key in database B does not exist in A, then the record is imported from B, and the ID of the new record is recorded.

Using the previously recorded ID, a mapping is created, explaining how to map foreign-key references to that specific record in B to the new merged/pre-existing record in A. When future records are merged into A, this mapping would be used to convert the foreign keys.

I could still envision some cases where an imported record references a table not included in the dumpdata, which might cause the entire import to fail, therefore some sort of "dryrun" option would be needed to simulate the import to ensure all FK references can be translated.

Does this seem like a practical approach? Is there a better way?

EDIT: This isn't exactly what I'm looking for, but I thought others might find it interesting. The [Turbion project](https://github.com/daevaorn/turbion/blob/master/turbion/bits/utils/tests/merging.py) has a mechanism for copying changes between equivalent records in different Django models within the same database. It works by defining a translation layer (i.e. merging.ModelLayer) between two Django models, so, say if you update the "www" field in user bob@bob.com's profile, it'll automatically update the "url" field in user bob@bob.com's otherprofile.

The functionality I'm looking for is a bit different, in that I want to merge an entire (or partial) database snapshot at infrequent intervals, sort of the way the loaddata management command does.

Answer (score 1):

Wow. This is going to be a complex job regardless. That said:

If I understand the needs of your project correctly, this can be something that can be done using a data migration in [South](http://south.aeracode.org/). Even so, I'd be lying if I said it was going to be a joke.

My recommendation is -- and this is mostly a parrot of an assumption in your question, but I want to make it clear -- that you have one "master" table that is the base, and which has records from the other table added to it. So, table A keeps all of its existing records, and only gets additions from B. B feeds additions into A, and once done, B is deleted.

I'm hesitant to write you sample code because your actual job will be so much more complex than this, but I will anyway to try and point you in the right direction. Consider something like...

```
import datetime
from south.db import db
from south.v2 import DataMigration
from django.db import models

class Migration(DataMigration):
    def forwards(self, orm):
        for b in orm.B.objects.all():
            # sanity check: does this item get copied into A at all?
            if orm.A.objects.filter(username=b.username):
                continue

            # make an A record with the properties of my B record
            a = orm.A(
                first_name=b.first_name,
                last_name=b.last_name,
                email_address=b.email_address,
                [...]
            )

            # save the new A record, and delete the B record
            a.save()
            b.delete()

    def backwards(self, orm):
        # backwards method, if you write one
```

This would end up migrating all of the Bs not in A to A, and leave you a table of Bs that are expected duplicates, which you could then check by some other means before deleting.

Like I said, this sample isn't meant to be complete. If you decide to go this route, spend time in the [South documentation](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/), and particularly make sure you look at [data migrations](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/tutorial/part3.html).

That's my 2¢. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. It sounds like you understand exactly what I want to do. However, I had ruled out South because I see their data migration feature as more of a "one off" that must be regenerated each time I would want to perform a merge.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "perform a merge". Are you referring to different tables? If so, that's correct. If you mean merging the same tables together, then you could just re-perform the migration (either by copying it with a later number or marking it unperformed), which would be vastly easier than any manual solution.

I'm not saying South is perfectly built for what you're doing, but you'll have a much easier time doing this job with South than with nothing.